# "Excel at something" vs. "excel in something"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions, collocation

I've come across a question while writing an exam

> Roger really excelled ***_*__** sports
>
> A) at
>   B) on
>   C) in
>   D) for

My first thought was 'in', later I remembered using 'at' also. I've searched for this in a few forums, there they say both 'excel in' and 'excel at' are correct expressions and could not really make out any differences.

Now my problem is that I'm an ESL and the above question doesn't give options like 'both a and c correct'. I'm not sure what option to pick for these kind of questions.

So, what is the correct option for above question?. Answers from experts are much appreciated. If both are correct what is the intention of question paper setter?

Comment: It's a bad question - although **on** and **for** are inarguably "incorrect/non-idiomatic" there's no justification for suggesting **at** is any "better" than **in**, or vice-versa. It's obviously not actually the *intention* of the question, but the *effect* of it is to show that the person who wrote the question is in the wrong job.

Comment: @FumbleFingers may be it's due to ignorance of question paper setters (copying the sentence from somewhere and making options themselves) I came across many instances of this kind.

Comment: It would probably help other users of this site if you posted ***links*** to any such examples (if only so people would know to avoid those sites, which are probably poor quality and thus not suitable for use as "learning resources").

Comment: A look at OALD would  answer your question.  to excel in/at something. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/excel?q=excel

Answer (score 8):

While 'excel at' and 'excel in' are generally interchangeable, I do think there is a subtle distinction.

*excel at* seems to apply better to specific activities.

> He excels at service returns in badminton.

*excel in* seems to apply better to more general categories or things that cover many activities.

> She excels in school.

To me, "She excels at school" sounds thoroughly ungrammatical and would not be uttered by a native speaker. "He excels in service returns in badminton" also sounds a little bit strange but other native speakers than me might use it.

Comment: 'She excels at school', sounds perfectly alright to my ear. I do however agree that 'at' works better with the service returns.  'He excels at quadratic equations',seems similar. You may be on to something when you say that 'at' applies better (I don't like your use of 'best' here) to specific activities.

Comment: @WS2, I will amend my ways and make them better instead of asserting that they are best!

Comment: Your answer is more agreeable than the others'

Comment: @virmaior and WS2:Good points both. "She excels at school" does not sound right to me either, but I'm not sure if there is a clear rule to exclude it.

Comment: My guess is that originally, excel was used mostly to describe being superior in some field of activity to which the preposition **in** applied, and so **in** has a longer history with the word. Later, usage expanded to include things to which **at** applied better than **in** (specific actions rather than fields of activity), and so **at** came to be used with _excel_ as well. Just a guess.

Comment: The OED citations (beginning in the 15th century) are almost all with '*in*'.  There are a couple of early 19th century citations  including *...excelling at the game...* and *...does not excel in the Spenser stanza...*.  There are no 20th or 21st century citations.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the intended correct answer is "in". You are good "at" something, but you excel "in" a sport or an activity.

Possibly it is also acceptable to say that someone excels "at" something, but "in" should be more correct. As in:

> Little Johnny excels in debate class. He also excels in sports and in many other activities.

Note that in the above example it might *sound* OK to say "excels **at** sports" or "excels **at** many other activities"-- but "excels **at** debate class" is clearly wrong.

So I would argue that **in** is the true, correct preposition to be used with "excel", and **at** is a late-comer that has slipped into usage because it is applicable to many (but not all) of the things that one can excel in and therefore *sounds* OK when used in those phrases.

**Update**

Merriam Webster online (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excel) gives examples of usage with both **at** and **in**:

> excel in sports
>
> excelled at lipreading

As they use 'in' in the phrase with 'sports', I maintain my position that **in** is more correct, at least in this specific case.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me an example for 'excel at' usage?

Comment: Well, you could say that someone 'excels at math', or 'excels at typing', or 'excels at sports', and these would sound correct to almost anyone you talked to. But I would argue that most likely they are all incorrect-- probably 'in' is the more correct pronoun.

Comment: But in wordweb software dictionary, the word 'excel at' gives meaning=be good at, where as 'excel in' returns no result....

Comment: Well, 'excel in' is definitely correct whether or not 'excel at' is also correct, so that is probably just an oversight in your software dictionary.

Comment: Merriam Webster online gives examples with both 'at' and 'in': http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excel

Comment: I found this example from that page   "to be distinguishable by superiority :  surpass others <excel in sports> <excelled at lipreading>" does plural 'sports' has anything to do with it? From another website https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/excel%20in#word=excel%20at

Comment: Doesn't having a direct dictionary entry imply that 'excel at' is more correct? I suspect that broadness of the term 'sports' has something to do with it!

Comment: That debate class is a red herring. You're saying that he excels (as a general notion) while he's in debate class; not that he is good at debate class—which should mean the same, but is also very strange. “He's good in debate class” works fine, though, even though you are good _at_ something.

Comment: Also, ‘in’ is a preposition—not a pronoun.

Comment: @Janus: Yes, I meant to say preposition, Freudian slip I guess.

Comment: Here's my hypothesis: in the phrases with which excel was _originally_ used, it was used with **in**. Later it came to be used with activities to which **at** applies better than **in**, and it was then that **at** came to be associated with _excel_. Evidence for this is that there does not appear to be an overwhelming reason to prefer **in** to **at** for _excels in sports_, yet **in** is clearly the more conventional and, perhaps, more correct choice for this phrase.

Comment: If the OED’s citations are anything to go by, _in_ is indeed the preposition that was used first, with quotes dating back to the very earliest uses of the verb in the 14th century. _At_, however, has been used with it at least since the 1600s and continues to be. I’d say whatever perceived need or difference that caused it to arise originally is by now lost.

Comment: Interesting bit of history.

Answer (score 2):

We use AT when we speak about sports, activities: excel at football.

And we use IN when we speak about academic subjects: excel in maths.

Answer (score 1):

In Britain 'excel at' and 'excel in' are to all intents interchangeable. I cannot think of any example of one where you couldn't with equal justification also use the other. Can anyone?

Responder's own edit:
 see @ virmajor reply. They may be on to something here.

Comment: Only place I can think of is the lyrics to Take That's _Back for Good_: “In the twist of separation, you excelled at being free”. And the only reason it doesn't work there is that that's just not how the lyrics to that song go.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with the notion that "at" sounds better for a specific activity or task while "in" sounds better for a general category.  That said, in my humble opinion - English is not my mother tongue - I think there is also a subtle nuance in the intended usage of "at" or "in".  When you hear someone say "she excels at school" and you find it alright, maybe you are thinking that that "at" does not denote "school" as a learning subject, but is a preposition of location.  In that case, the sentence can be paraphrased "at school, she excels (in many things)".